# Wix-downgrade option is not working even when i set "yes" in Major upgrade tag

Tags: wix, wix3.7

Please see below bundle file

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
 <Bundle Name="Boot_Demo" Version="2.0.0" Manufacturer="Demo-Product" UpgradeCode="{8B19CAE6-59BD-4001-958B-9D2E9F9A1B4D}">

  <Chain>
   <!-- TODO: Define the list of chained packages. -->
   <!-- <MsiPackage SourceFile="path\to\your.msi" /> -->

      <MsiPackage SourceFile="D:\Jayesh\TestProjects\Demo-Product\Demo-Product\bin\Debug\Demo-Product.msi"
                  DisplayInternalUI="yes"
                  Visible="yes"
                  ForcePerMachine="yes"
                  Permanent="no"
                  Vital="yes"
                  EnableFeatureSelection="yes"
       >
      </MsiPackage>
  </Chain>
 </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

am getting same error while downgrading with different versions .

am used first 2.0.0 in bundle file and product.wxs file. Then I have given 1.0.0.